# Cannot build project using Mono for Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

When i try to build and run my project i get the following build errors:

```
HourScreen.cs(13,13): Error CS0433: The imported type `System.Net.WebRequest' is defined    multiple times (CS0433)
HourScreen.cs(17,17): Error CS0433: The imported type `System.Net.WebResponse' is defined multiple times (CS0433)
```

The lines on which the errors happen look like this:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
```

I include the following into the project:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.Preferences;
using Android.Graphics;
```

I think one of the includes must be playing up but i have no idea which. Removing one causes a huge load of other errors. Can anyone see where im going wrong?

**EDIT:**

I've included the build log: http://pastebin.com/FrmzfhcY

Comment: It won't be namespace related but assembly related. Please edit your post to show how this assembly was compiled, i.e. so we can see every references.

Comment: I could not find the assembly browser in MonoDevelop, how can i access  it? Sorry but i'm still quite new to this.

Comment: There's a "Build Output" button in MonoDevelop's "Error List" pane that will show you the compilation log. That should include everything referenced (and be easy to copy-paste).

Comment: I've added the build log to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HourScreen.cs(167,17): error CS0433: The imported type `System.Net.WebResponse' is defined multiple times
                /Developer/MonoAndroid/usr/lib/mono/2.1/System.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
                /Mono for Android/Bups_Urenverantwoording 1.0/Bups_Urenverantwoording/bin/Debug/System.Net.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
```

The log has your answer. Mono for Android provides it's own `System.Net` stack in `System.dll` but you're also including other assemblies, like `System.Net.dll` which includes the same type.

Since you also reference `System.Windows.dll` I assume you're trying to include some code from Silverlight (or Moonlight) and that won't work. At least not for for `System.Net.dll` (not sure what you're trying to use from `System.Windows.dll`).

Comment: I had added a file from a different project into my new project. That file had a load of includes to different System.Window which wernt even used. Removing them solved the error. Thanks for your help!